# How can I update multiple collections in Meteor in the same transaction?

Tags: meteor

I have the following client-side code (with two collections `A` and `B`):

```
var id = A.insert({name: 'new element of A');
var b = B.findOne({name: 'parent of new element of A'});
B.update(b._id, { $set: { child: id } });
```

The above code works fine, i.e., the server side collections are correctly updated. The problem happens on the client where I have a template that reacts on both `A` and `B` collection changes.

The template reacts as follows:

1. It immediately redraws itself, based on the latency compensation mechanism, showing the correct changes for both collections
2. Soon after, it redraws itself again but without the changes (as if they had been rejected)
3. It does not refresh automatically anymore afterwards. But, if I hit the refresh button, the template redraws once more and now shows the correctly updated collections (both `A` and `B`)

On the second refresh only one of the collection (the parent `B`) has been updated and the template displays incoherent data (as if the updates had not happened).

I think this is because I am not dealing here with one single transaction that updates both collections at the same time, confusing the client side template.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

I must add that in my case I have two complementing subscriptions to the child database:

```
var A = new Meteor.Collection('children');

handle1 = Meteor.subscribe('children1');
handle2 = Meteor.subscribe('children2');
```

and on the server

```
Meteor.publish('children1', function () {
    return A.find({ sex: male });
}
Meteor.publish('children2', function () {
    return A.find({ sex: female });
}
```

Could this be the reason for, when I insert a new element in A, I get the weird behavior described above?

Comment: Meteor doesn't support transactions (yet). Think it's on the roadmap though

Answer (score 0):

it might work better if you do it all in one command

```
B.update({name: 'parent of new element of A'}, { $set: { child: A.insert({name: 'new element of A') } });
```

you'll have to put this in a method since you arent updating based on the id

you could also try to manually call `Deps.flush()` after the operations, that shouldnt be needed, but its something to try

Comment: Tried both inlining and `Deps.flush()` but no better result.